# How to Read VM monitoring data from Azure site?

Tags: azure

There is no Management API for reading azure monitoring data. Is there any way other than getting the monitoring data directly from a VM through remote desktop connection? We basically want to display a chart for "CPU usage percentage Vs. Time”. Actually, Azure site displays monitoring data for each VM-is there any way I can read that data and display it in a report? Any PowerShell cmdlets?

Answer (score 0):

Suggested good related articles:

- [How to monitor Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-monitor-a-cloud-service/)
- [Enabling Diagnostics in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/)

If you, however refer to [Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/) then you have to organize monitoring of these a similar way you would organize a monitoring over machines in private cloud (hyper-v)

Comment: Hi astaykov,thank you very much for your reply.But could you please explain little bit further on this? Should I run my own program in the Virtual machine(by connecting the Azure VMs remotely)? Microsfot is planning to release any Management APIs/Powershell Cmdlets for this in the near future?

Comment: Please read the provided materials before asking new questions.

Comment: Thanks Astaykov..We already completed analyzing the links provided by you a long back..and nothing turned out to be helpful..May be we did not understand the material properly,but we could not find a straight forward way to monitor a Azure VM(without acually runing our own program in the VM remotely).

Comment: Are you using [Cloud Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/cloud-services/) or [Azure Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/virtual-machines/). Sorry, but it is completely non-understandable from your question and comments. Because if you just the latter, you monitor them the same way you monitor **any** Windows/Linux machine regardless of where this OS is installed. If you struggle more, you can hire a consultant to show you how to do the monitoring.

Comment: Hello, Even I am facing the same trouble. I want to get the analytic data about the VM in my own application. Monitoring API for .NET is available at present but not REST. Is there any other way to Monitor the VM instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the CPU data for cloud services (Web/workers and VMs) through the Azure Metrics API, see: https://convective.wordpress.com/2014/06/22/using-azure-monitoring-service-with-azure-virtual-machines/

You can find example code in https://github.com/WadGraphEs/AzurePlot